# Parse Windows CSV on Linux in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, codepages

I am trying to parse a CSV file coming from a Windows machine on a Linux machine using Apache Spark, but accentuated characters do not seem to be recognized...

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
    .read()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("file.csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're almost there. Try:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
    .read()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("encoding", "cp1252")
    .load("file.csv");
```

You can specify the `encoding`as an option. For Windows, it's cp1252.

Comment: cp1252 = Windows?

Comment: Most likely... Specially if your file comes from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run a `dos2unix` command on the file from inside a `Terminal` once it is brought to linux.

`dos2unix <file_name>`

This will make sure that the carriage return characters to be removed from the file and it will become linux friendly.